# Cant make sample sender and receiver work

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I get this while running cast-sender-tool-chrome ( web_sender_tool.html )

```
API Status: "Initialized"
Receivers Available: "Yes"
Session Established: "ERROR: {\"code\":\"session_error\",\"description\":\"NOT_FOUND\",\"details\":null}"
Last Message Received: N/A
```

Trying to understand what happen, in the receiver

https://googledrive.com/host/0B-Xkvxnj_z2JblZXSXFiZ2hfMlE/sample_media_receiver.html

i get this:

```
 [  0.032s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Opening message bus websocket
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.033s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Opening the WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.035s] [goog.net.WebSocket] An error occurred: undefined
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.036s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IpcChannel error
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.036s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system, SystemSender]: {"type":"error"}
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.037s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] CastReceiverManager message received: [object Object]
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.038s] [goog.net.WebSocket] The WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc closed.
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.038s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IpcChannel closed
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.039s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system, SystemSender]: {"type":"closed"}
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  0.039s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] CastReceiverManager message received: [object Object]
```

I'm using fedora 19 with google-chrome-beta ( 33 ).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking.   The easiest way to get started is use a sample sender app like this: https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideo-chrome but keep the default media receiver.  Once you confirm that you get a list of devices pop-out from Chrome Cast extension and you can cast, you may change your receiver to your own and iterate from there.

Comment: i make it work when activate to send info to google